# vm stuck on hyper-v splash screen

Tags: hyper-v

The hyper-v host has 256Gb of ram but the Centos VMs on it won't start with memory over 2Gb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XELmF.png)

Comment: If you turn the VM off and restart the VM, will it still stuck on Hyper-V loading screen?  Also check the event log to see if there are something related.

Comment: I can find anything in the log that points me to that error